# Propel2 is not prefixing classes or filenames with the classPrefix

Tags: propel

As stated, propel2 is not prefixing the generated classes or filenames with the defined classPrefix. Here is my yaml file.

```
propel:
paths:
    schemaDir: generated-reversed-database

database:
    connections:
        default:
            adapter: 
            dsn: 
            user: 
            password: 

runtime:
    defaultConnection: default 
    connections:
        - default 

generator:
    defaultConnection: default 
    connections:
        - default

    objectModel:
        addHooks: false
        classPrefix: ABC_
```

Edit: I felt like I was missing information to help clarify the situation. Classes being generated are such as TableName.php => class TableName extends BaseTableName and I'm expecting class ABC_TableName extends BaseTableName or maybe ABC_TableName extends ABC_Base_TableName to handle class naming based on pathing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct fix for this is to do a mass replace on the phpName property in the schema file. The classPrefix property in the configuration is misleading or currently not implemented properly?